# Meaning of ようともしない

Tags: grammar, particle-も, volitional-form

I'm familiar with ようとする to mean "try to" or "about to", but how about this:

> 新聞から顔を上げようともしない。

Obviously that's a negation of ようとする with an added も. I'm guessing も adds a hint of "even" to the phrase. Does the phrase still retain the 'try' meaning?

> He doesn't/didn't even try to look up from his newspaper.

Adding 'try' seems a bit strange since looking up from a newspaper is not a difficult or demanding activity.

Or is it maybe a volitional thing e.g.

> He wasn't even prepared to look up from his newspaper.

Or can it be both, depending on context, or something else altogether?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The auxiliary verb う/よう denotes the subject's *will* in a broad sense, and you don't have to use "try" in a case like this. I think "He *won't/wouldn't* even look up from his newspaper" is enough.

You can see other example sentences in these dictionaries:

- [ALC](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84&ref=sa)
- [Weblio](http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%22%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%22)